# Why are class level variables not accessible by methods in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and typescript. This is the relevant code:

```
export class SearchBarComponent {
    constructor() { }

    public timeDelay = 9999;

    onSubmit(event){

        console.log(this.timeDelay);

    }
}
```

I would expect:

```
typed 9999
```

Instead, I get:

```
typed undefined
```

My first guess was that it might have to do with timeDelay being private but setting it to public made no difference. As you can see below I easily found a workaround, however, I'm still curious about this odd behaviour.

One thing of note is that if I define the class variable in the method it's self (this.timeDelay = 9999)  that it remembers it the next time I access it, therefore there must be something I don't understand in the way TypeScript class variables compile into JS.

This is the full code dump in case I'm missing something else:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-bar',
  templateUrl: './search-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-bar.component.scss'],
})
export class SearchBarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let searchbar = document.querySelector('ion-searchbar');
    searchbar.addEventListener('ionInput', this.onSubmit);
  }

  //Used by onSubmit() method to record last input time
  lastInputTime = null;

  public timeDelay = 9999;

  //called on every user input
  //detects whether the user has stopped typing for an arbitrary amount of time and calls search method
  onSubmit(event){

    console.log("typed " + this.timeDelay);

    //technically it's being defined here because defining it outside doesn't appear to work
    this.lastInputTime = Date.now();

    // ToDo import from settings file
    // In milliseconds
    const timeDelay = 1000;

    setTimeout(
        () => {
          console.log(timeDelay + " " + (Date.now() - this.lastInputTime) + " " + this.lastInputTime);

          //Detect if there was any keystroke in the last timeDelay
          //-10 is a buffer
          if (Date.now() - this.lastInputTime >= timeDelay - 10) {
            console.log("submit: " +  event.target.value.toLowerCase());
          }
        },
        timeDelay
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why you declare property, after methods ? Property should be declared before the constructor, and before methods...

Comment: You did not type it. You can type it as a number. `public timeDelay: number = 9999;`

Comment: Why are you accessing/querying the DOM? It is recommended to use output directives/properties on the component. `<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="onSubmit($event)">`

Comment: @Silvermind Good point, that also binds the component to the class. I'll change my code to use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onSubmit` variable is being executed in a different context. Therefore, inside your `onSubmit` method, `this` has a different value to the rest of your class.

You need to bind the `this` context to your method like so:

```
searchbar.addEventListener('ionInput', this.onSubmit.bind(this));
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rqhdvl) Stackblitz demonstration.

Edit:
For anyone coming across this in the future, the proper solution would be to bind the component directly using `<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="onSubmit($event)"></ion-searchbar>`.

Comment: You nailed it, thank you! I had no idea the bind method even existed.